# Difference var foo and var $foo

Tags: javascript, variables

Searched for duplicates but couldn't find any..

Is there any substantial difference between:

```
var $foo = $(this);
```

and

```
var foo = $(this);
```

??

Comment: No difference. `$` is a valid character in variables. Just a visual cue that it is a jQuery object.

Comment: No difference at all...

Comment: There's no functional difference, but it's the convention to prefix variables denoting jQuery objects with `$`.

Comment: were you looking for `this` vs `$(this)` ?

Comment: @elclanrs: Do turn that into an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No difference. `$` is a valid character in variables. It's a visual cue that tells you that's a jQuery object.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - [visual cue is correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_cue)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I had to look it up too, I'm like "pretty sure 'cue' is what I meant".